# Unable to send HTML form data to email using PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I have tried to send the form data to my email id. unfortunately it is not working and not getting any email from it.

I deployed into the server to test.

Experts inputs please?

here my try,

**index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
 <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sender">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>mail id</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="senderEmail">
            </div>           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mobile. No</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">

        </form>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $recipient="mohan@gmail.com";
    $subject="New mail";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];      
    $mobile=$_POST["mobile"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

} 

?>
```

Comment: Less secure app access on after try

Comment: What server are you running this from? The server needs to have some sort of mail agent that uses SMTP running in order for the PHP mail() function to work properly